# How are the rest api calls done in openstack?

Tags: python, openstack

How are the rest api calls done in openstack in coding module i.e.python code? Which module implements rest apis?

Comment: Is this as a user or as an operator?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you're interacting with and how.

If it's for [Nova/Compute](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/), there's [python-novaclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-novaclient/).

If it's for [Swift/Object Storage](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/), there's [python-swiftclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-swiftclient).

The list goes on, including a keystoneclient, glanceclient, cinderclient, etc. There's a fairly recent [openstack-client](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-openstackclient/) that tries to unify all of these.

If you want one library to rule them all, at the moment you can use [pyrax](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrax/) to interface with any OpenStack deployment.

Comment: As a operator.Can you elaborate it?